# Unix cut based on order in column

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a bash script that returns something like the following:

```
/title
my_title
/year
2017
```

How can I pull out the year (2017) using a simple cut command (or something of the sort than can be scripted)?

I know `cut -d\  -f2` would work if the title didn't exist... so how do I skip over title and grab only the year?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ sed -n '/\/year/{n;p;q}' infile
2017
```

This does:

```
/\/year/ { # If the line matches "year"
    n      # Get next line
    p      # Print line
    q      # Quit: don't have to read the rest of the file
}
```

`-n` makes sure nothing else gets printed.

Comment: Thanks... what if I wanted to incorporate this into a script itself.  In place of the cut command.

    out="$(bin/getYear.sh)"
    year="$(echo $out | cut -d\ -f2)"

Comment: @K.R. `year="$(sed -n '/\/year/{n;p;q}' infile)"`?

Comment: @K.R. You can replace `infile` by the output of your script: `year="$(sed -n '/\/year/{n;p;q}' <(bin/getYear.sh))"`

Answer (score 2):

If 4 digit year appearing in a separate line as shown then you can use awk:

```
awk 'p=="/year"{print; exit} {p=$0}' file
2017
```

Answer (score 2):

another `awk`

```
$ awk 'f{print;exit} /^\/year/{f=1}' file
2017
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is exactly as shown, cut would not work at all, since it works on one line at a time.

You can use `tail` to get the last line:

```
tail -n 1
```

or the fourth line:

```
tail -n+4
```

or `grep` + `tail` to get the line follwing `/year`:

```
grep -A1 'year' | tail -n1
```

`grep -A1` will print one line following the matched flag, which you then extract with tail.